# PHP regular expression with optional underscore and number

Tags: php, nsregularexpression

I want a PHP regular expression that must start from 1 to 5 lower case characters, followed by an optional underscore, and then followed by 0 to 5 numbers/digits.

This is my code: `'/[a-z][_][0-9]/'`

Comment: "[a-z]{1,5}_?[0-9]{0,5}"

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/59331742/2908724

Answer (score 2):

You're close. You need range and optional sigils:

```
/[a-z]{1,5}_?[0-9]{0,5}/
```

The expression `{n,m}` following a character class means the class must match *at least* `n` times and *at most* `m` times.

The expression `?` following a character means the character must match 0 or 1 times. It's equivalent to `{0,1}`, just shorter.

If this doesn't work for your subject strings, please post some example matches and non-matches.